# If the keyboard is appear, the resize bottom inset is not working when i am using with webview_flutter in flutter. How can i fix this bug?

Tags: android, flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

Here is the simple code that are using for the webview. The used package is webview_flutter: ^4.4.4.

```
class ScreenWebview extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenWebview({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    GetWebViewController controller = Get.find();

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Obx(
          () => controller.isLoading.value
              ? const Center(child: LoadingWidget())
              : WebViewWidget(controller: controller.webController),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is the controller part

```
class WebViewBinding implements Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut(() => WebViewController());
  }
}

class WebViewController extends GetxController {
  RxBool isLoading = false.obs;
  late WebViewController webController;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    controllerInitialize();
  }

  void controllerInitialize() {
    isLoading.value = true;
    webController = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setBackgroundColor(Get.theme.colorScheme.surface)
      ..enableZoom(false)
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/"));
    isLoading.value = false;
  }
}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

---

**Expectation:** If the keyboard appears, the auto resize will work and change ui for me.